# variable might already have been assigned when it cannot be assigned

Tags: java, try-catch, final

research this code:

```
public class TestFinalAndCatch {
    private final int i;

    TestFinalAndCatch(String[] args) {
        try {
            i = method1();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            i = 0;  // error: variable i might already have been assigned
        }
    }

    static int method1() throws IOException {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

compiler says that `java: variable i might already have been assigned`

But for me it is looks like impossible situation.

Comment: This is a really good answer to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17075219/1354590

Comment: And the workaround is already presented here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13604193/1354590

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that in this case compiler works syntax-based not semantic-based.
There are 2 workarounds:
First base on moving exception handle on method:

```
package com.java.se.stackoverflow;

public class TestFinalAndCatch {
    private final int i;

    TestFinalAndCatch(String[] args) {
        i = method1();
    }

    static int method1() {
        try {
            return 1;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Second base on using temporar variable:

```
package com.java.se.stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestFinalAndCatch {
    private final int i;

    TestFinalAndCatch(String[] args) {
        int tempI;
        try {
            tempI = method1();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            tempI = 0;
        }
        i = tempI;
    }

    static int method1() throws IOException {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the best answers on SO I have come across.

Answer (score 8):

`i` is final, so it can only be assigned once. The compiler is probably not smart enough to realize that if an exception is thrown, the first assignment won't take place, and if an exception isn't thrown, the second assignment won't take place.

Comment: Yes, but my situation like if  else

Comment: no.. its not like if else. it may happen that your i get assigned and then your code throws exception

Comment: @Adi in my situation it is impossible

Comment: Yes. but compiler doesn't understand that. like Eran said, it is not 'smart enough' :).

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this problem, use a local variable in the try catch block and then assign that result to the instance variable.

```
public class TestFinalAndCatch {
    private final int i;

    TestFinalAndCatch(String[] args) {
        int tmp;
        try {
            tmp = method1();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            tmp = 0;
        }
        i = tmp;
    }

    static int method1() throws IOException {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm.. thanks, but I don't want to overcome this problem)) question about how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6326693?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Looks like JDK bug. And now status - Fixed. But I cannot find from which version.

Comment: No, this was a bug when a final variable was assigned in multiple *catch* blocks, not in the `try` and `catch`. Also, this bug is fixed in Java 8.